# Backup elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, backup

Is it possible to get backup of index from elasticksearch by http rest interface?

Can I just send http-request and get snapshot without creating snapshot repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Want to store as elasticsearch restorable file?

You can store [snapshots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) of individual indices or an entire cluster in a remote repository like a shared file system, S3, or HDFS.

Want to store as JSON so you can use the data outside es?

[elasticdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump) works by sending an input to an output. Both can be either an elasticsearch URL or a File.

CSV?

https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv